# Observer stop working when object changed Vue.js

Tags: vue.js, pug

When I add dynamic keys in object, the observer in inputs stops working. For example:

```
<template lang="pug">
 input#field(v-model="block[current]")
 button(@click="current = 'de'") change
 button(@click="addVal") add
 
</template>
<script>
data() {
 return {
   current: "en"
   block: {}
 }
},
methods: {
 addVal() {
   this.block.de = "adawdawdawd";
 }
}

</script>
```

Now if I type in `#fiel`, `block.de` wont work. But if I'm not adding values, it works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to  use `this.$set` to update it because you have a reactivity issue:

```
this.$set(this.block,"de" , "adawdawdawd");
```

Comment: how i can set it if my code is: `block.fields[key].value[lang.value] = block.fields[key].value[this.computed_languages.default]`

Comment: Maybe u know if i have values: default.value, and current.value.. How i can set `current.value = default.value` But withot observer, for default.value will not changed by current.value when i change current.value?

Comment: what do you mean by without observer

Comment: if i set `current.value = default.value` in data, and ill only change `current.value`, `default.value` will change automatticaly. I drop observer now with `JSON.stringify(default.value)`. and use it like = `current.value = JSON.parse(default.value)` In this case obserwer will drops. But maybe vuejs have another way.

Comment: Vuejs way is to use `$set` method